# Is it bad practice to make expectations on unknown hardware devices?

Tags: device-driver

While adapting a linux device driver to include another device of a certain vendor, I came across about 20 USB device id's the driver is matched against. It turns out that any of this devices used the same interface, and just adding the new device id lead to another working device instantly. However, there are about 30 unsupported devices left. In this example, the device is one of several different sized touchscreens, assumedly all based upon the same controller.

Now I came upon the question why not to include the device id's of all devices, or even some wildcard matching, supposedly making a driver that would work with any of this devices.

Of course some device may be incompatible, and lead to issues. But well-standardized devices (like SATA or HID devices) are prone to incompatibilities too.

Is there a strong argument against having such a 'wildcard' driver?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing 2 different things here. Specific device works via USB/SATA etc. HW interfaces (and via corresponding lower-level HW interface driver), but that doesn't imply anything about specifics of one device or another - that's proprietary. A driver may support more than a single device, normally it would be a family of similar devices from the same vendor but support for other devices can't be deduced from this fact. As an example, consider USB camera and USB memory stick. Both work via the same USB interface but their functionality is completely different, even if they come from the same vendor.

Comment: I will not deduct from a mice to a camera.. Just using the known usb-ids of all screens of one series, the only visible difference is their physical dimension. And all known devices (about 20) of them use the same interface. So I expect the left 30 ones to use it too. Which may be wrong.

Comment: Only the vendor can answer that. If a device isn't originally supported by the driver, the underlying HW/FW isn't designed to work with it, even if it's from the same vendor and look similar. Attempt to force the driver to work with unsupported device will be undefined behavior in best case and crash in the worst.